# How do I debug this gulp issue in laravel 5.2?

Tags: javascript, php, gulp, laravel-5

I run gulp and everything from the terminal seems fine.

```
var gulp = require('gulp-help')(require('gulp'));
var elixir = require('laravel-elixir');
const debug = require('gulp-debug');


/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Elixir Asset Management
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------   
|
| Elixir provides a clean, fluent API for defining some basic Gulp tasks
| for your Laravel application. By default, we are compiling the Sass
| file for our application, as well as publishing vendor resources.
|
*/

elixir(function(mix) {
    mix.sass(['app.scss', 'controller.scss']);

});


elixir(function(mix) {

    mix.scripts([ 'assets/js/vendor/jquery.min.js', 'assets/js/vendor/tether.min.js', 'controllers.js', 'assets/js/vendor/holder.min.js','custom/js/script.js'], 'public/js/all.js').browserify('all.js');

    mix.version(["css/app.css",  "js/all.js" ]);

});
```

The generated file instead contained this:
(function e(t,n,r){function s(o,u){if(!n[o]){if(!t[o]){var a=typeof require=="function"&&require;if(!u&&a)return a(o,!0);if(i)return i(o,!0);var f=new Error("Cannot find module '"+o+"'");throw f.code="MODULE_NOT_FOUND",f}var l=n[o]={exports:{}};t[o][0].call(l.exports,function(e){var n=t[o](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ANmGQ.png)[e];return s(n?n:e)},l,l.exports,e,t,n,r)}return n[o].exports}var i=typeof require=="function"&&require;for(var o=0;o

},{}]},{},[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ANmGQ.png));

so the javascript link on the page is empty as shown in the image below

[image]

Seems ok from the terminal as shown below
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think it has something with your paths here, can you try this:

```
mix.scripts([ 
   'vendor/jquery.min.js', '
   'vendor/tether.min.js', 
   'controllers.js', 
   'vendor/holder.min.js',
   'custom/js/script.js'
],'public/js/all.js')
.browserify(['../../public/js/all.js'],'public/js/all.js');
```

`scripts` and `browserify` use `resources\assets\js` as root paths where they search the script files, and browserify creates a file named `bundle.js`. You need to write the file two times, first when generating the `scripts` output, and last overwriting with browserify.